# Multiple inputs for text specification prediction in ML.Net

Tags: .net, machine-learning, text-classification, ml.net

I have a **Category** and **Value** model built on ML.Net. **Category** is my label and the prediction. If I pass a single input it gives me the prediction accordingly.

I want to input multiple inputs for a particular **Category** and get predication according to that. Because it's very accurate than the single input.

I want to pass a string array to my model and get the predicted category. The string array represents a single category. (All strings belong to one category)

The data looks like this

| Category1 | Category2 | Category3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | Item5 | Item9 |
| Item2 | Item6 | Item10 |
| Item3 | Item7 | Item11 |
| Item4 | Item8 | Item12 |

Please suggest to me any idea for achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for but you can take a look at this tutorial which uses multiple inputs to predict a category.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/health-violation-classification-model-builder

Comment: Thank you @Luis for your support. I want to pass a string array to my model and get the predicted category. The string array represents a single category. (All strings belong to one category)

Comment: I'm not sure what your data looks like but maybe this might be something to look at. If you have an array of string, you'll want to convert them into numbers. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/prepare-data-ml-net#work-with-text-data

Comment: I Update how the data looks like. Each string array belongs to one category. I need to identify which is the correct category. The same strings can appear in different categories.